# How do we know which way a reversible interaction goes

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

Some particle interactions are reversible. For example, an electron can be converted into the associated neutrino, with emission of a $W^{-}$ (or absorption of a $W^{+}$):
\begin{equation}
e^{-} \rightarrow \nu_{e} + W^{-}
\end{equation}
The reverse process seems also possible:
\begin{equation}
\nu_{e} + W^{-} \rightarrow e^{-} 
\end{equation}
My question is: under what conditions the interaction goes one way, and under what conditions it goes the other way? In general, how do we know which way a reversible interaction goes?

Comment: It is as said by accidentalfouriertransform . Qft gives diagrams which do not care about which of the particles are your initial states

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform- The reverse process of the first interaction, i.e., $\nu_{e} + W^{-} \rightarrow e^{-}$, seems also possible. Then, if the first interaction takes place, will it goes back?

Comment: @Shen There definitely is some _probability_ for that to happen. If you had only a single electron, then presumably the neutrino and W boson would fly apart before the reverse reaction could happen; if you had a gas of those, then it seems much more likely (albeit with different particles).

Comment: @Demosthene If there is a gas of $\nu_{e}$ and $W^{-}$, electrons will be produced. What follows is that electrons will convert to  $\nu_{e}$ and $W^{-}$ again. Then, it seems that these two interactions oscillate. Is this true? I doubt it.

Comment: Real $W$ bosons are not stable.